# Google Tag Manager get user ID and time onClick

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have button with ID on the website.
At the moment we track button click with Tag Manager and Analytics.
But I would like to know, is there a way to save information about user ID and time when button was clicked?
Looking forward for any information.
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "user ID" ? There is a feature in Google Analytics called "userID" (which is for cross device tracking). Or do you mean the clientId (which GA uses to aggregate Hits into sessions), or do you mean an ID that is generated by your site ? Time is automatically tracked (at least down to the minute).

Comment: Dear Eike, speaking about "user ID", I meant _"userID" (which is for cross device tracking)_ . I have many buttons on the website and I would like to get information about userID and time when button was clicked. I would like to store this information in Google Analytics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in the following way:
 - Created variables in Google Tag Manager (GTM) which track the user ID and the date & time.
I already had tags which tracked button clicks on the website, so I added these variables in the categories of Tags ("Label" and "Value")
[Click event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q6ye.png)
Every time user click on the button, these variables track information about ID and date&time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess user ID, what you mentioned is internal ID in your website. First of all, you need to find a way how to receive user ID in your system. It can be many ways.

For example, let's say that your website has hidden input with user ID which has id="user-id" and you want to track button "Track this button". Basic html code if your page is:

```
<input type="hidden" id="user-id" value="unqieuserid123"/>
<button id="button-id">Track this button</button>
```

1. You need to create user defined variable (Variables->User-Defined Variables->New). Choose "Javascript" and enter name "UserId" and this code:

   ```
   function () {
       return document.getElementById("user-id") != null ? 
                  document.getElementById("user-id").value : ""
   }
   ```

   At the end it should be like that:[image]
2. Create variable for receiving user time (it will write user local time) with name "UserTime" and javascript code:

   ```
       function() {
           // Get local time as ISO string with offset at the end
           var now = new Date();
           var tzo = -now.getTimezoneOffset();
           var dif = tzo >= 0 ? '+' : '-';
           var pad = function(num) {
               var norm = Math.abs(Math.floor(num));
               return (norm < 10 ? '0' : '') + norm;
           };
           return now.getFullYear() 
               + '-' + pad(now.getMonth()+1)
               + '-' + pad(now.getDate())
               + 'T' + pad(now.getHours())
               + ':' + pad(now.getMinutes()) 
               + ':' + pad(now.getSeconds())
               + '.' + pad(now.getMilliseconds())
               + dif + pad(tzo / 60) 
               + ':' + pad(tzo % 60);
       }
   ```

   At the end it should be like that:[image]
3. Enable built-in variable `Click Element` if it is not enabled yet.
4. Create new trigger, for your button. In my case it is like that:[image]
5. Create new tag for tracking and sending data to GA. Here you can use your variables created on step #1 and #2. Like  `{{UserId}}` and `{{UserTime}}`. In my example it is like that:[image]
6. At the end in Google Analytics you will receive event with this label:

   `'user id: unqieuserid123; user time: 2017-05-31T12:20:19.06+04:00'`

Comment: Dear Viktor,
I am very grateful to you for such a detailed reply.
Yes, speaking about the ID of the button, I meant ID in the HTML code.
The only thing I don't understand and would like to clarify is why we need to create input.
If I understand correctly, this method can be suitable for tracking a single button on the website, but if we need to track many buttons clicks, this method is time consuming and not suitable in this case.
Do I understand correctly?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, do you want to track ID of button and time, when user clicks?

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to track which of the many buttons was clicked (at the moment I do it with GTM triggers) and when button was clicked I would like to track information about userID and time of click.

Comment: But what you mean userID?

Comment: Dear Victor, I mean feature in Google Analytics called "userID" (which is for cross device tracking).

Comment: Right. That means that you need somehow create and set correctly {{userId}} variable in GTM. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/4565987?hl=en It is still need some servers side changes. For ex. You developers can write userID to javascript global variable and hidden input or cookie. Question is do you already have userID variable in GTM? Or it is part of your initial question how to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is part of my initial question how to do that) As I understand, by accessing the website for the first time each user gets a unique ID by Google Analytics. I am at the beginning of study of GA and perhaps there is no such possibility, so please correct me if I am wrong. My idea is to track userID and time of click, when user clicked a specific button. I would like to handle all button clicks on the website.

Comment: Is it possible to realise it with dataLayer?

Comment: Actually it is a bit different. In GA they have client ID and used ID. Each user gets a unique client ID by Google Analytics, but it is not cross devices. Meantime for the user ID, your website should tell to GA this userID. For example for each user on your website you have integer ID field, that means that you need to pass this ID to GA if user logged in. That means if user logged in Chrome and in Mozilla with the same account, you website will tell GA that it is user XX